# Detect if a word is inside a sentence in Assembly NASM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, nasm, 32-bit

So basically I have this code where I need to check if a word is inside a sentence and I have no clue in how to do it. It's my first week learning assembly sorry.
Im making my own sql but in local just to try and so far I have checked if a word is equal to another word but I cant think of a way to detect if it is inside a sentence.
In the code I read an archive line by line and then I jmp to "siguiente_palabraDeseado" where I have to search "palabra2" inside "palabraaux".

I just need an example on how to do it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Just in case you want to see the whole code(This isnt necessary, just with an example I would be ok)
but If you want to try it

```
section .data
    frase db 100 dup(0) 
    longitud equ 100    
    palabra1 db 100 dup(0)
    palabra2 db 100 dup(0) 
    palabra3 db 100 dup(0) 
    palabraAux db 100 dup(0) ;Palabra auxiliar para guardar la de los archivos
    fraseAux db 100 dup(0) ;Frase auxiliar para guardar la de los archivos
    error db "No se pudo abrir el archivo.", 10
    errorLen equ $ - error
    error2 db "No se pudo leer el archivo.", 10
    errorLen2 equ $ - error2
    error3 db "Orden no encontrada.", 10
    errorLen3 equ $ - error3
    error4 db "Archivo cerrado incorrectamente.", 10
    errorLen4 equ $ - error4
    saltoLinea db 10,0
    select db "select",0
    insert db "insert",0
    exitText db "exit",0
    todo db "*",0
    prueba db "Llego hasta aqui",10     ;para poder hacer debug
    pruebaLen equ $ - prueba

section .bss
    fileIdentificator resb 100
    content resb 4096

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, 100     ; Cantidad de bites a limpiar

    ; Limpiar palabra1
    mov edi, palabra1 ; Dirección base de palabra1
    xor eax, eax     ; Valor cero
    rep stosb        ; Almacenar valor cero en ecx bytes desde edi

    ; Limpiar palabra2
    mov edi, palabra2 ; Dirección base de palabra2
    xor eax, eax     ; Valor cero
    rep stosb        ; Almacenar valor cero en ecx bytes desde edi

    ; Limpiar palabra3
    mov edi, palabra3 ; Dirección base de palabra3
    xor eax, eax     ; Valor cero
    rep stosb        ; Almacenar valor cero en ecx bytes desde edi

    ; Limpiar fileIdentificator
    mov edi, [fileIdentificator] ; Dirección base de fileIdentificator
    mov eax, 0     ; Valor cero
    rep stosb        ; Almacenar valor cero en ecx bytes desde edi

    ; Limpiar palabra auxiliar
    mov edi, palabraAux ; Dirección base de fileIdentificator
    xor eax, eax     ; Valor cero
    rep stosb        ; Almacenar valor cero en ecx bytes desde edi

    ; nuevaLinea
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, saltoLinea
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ; nuevaLinea
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, saltoLinea
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h



    ; Leer la frase ingresada por el usuario
    mov eax, 3                  ; Número de llamada al sistema para leer
    mov ebx, 0                  ; Descriptor de archivo (stdin)
    mov ecx, frase              ; Puntero al búfer de entrada
    mov edx, longitud           ; Longitud máxima de entrada
    int 80h                    ; Llamar al sistema operativo

    ; Inicializar los registros
    mov ebx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la frase
    mov ecx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la palabra
    mov edi, palabra1 ; Dirección de la primera palabra

recorrer_frase:
    ; Verificar si hemos llegado al final de la frase
    cmp ebx, longitud
    jge siguiente_palabra

    ; Obtener el carácter actual
    mov al, [frase + ebx]

    ; Verificar si es un espacio en blanco
    cmp al, ' '
    je siguiente_palabra

    ; Almacenar el carácter en la palabra correspondiente
    mov [edi + ecx], al

    ; Incrementar el contador de posición en la palabra
    inc ecx
    jmp siguiente_caracter

siguiente_caracter:
    ; Incrementar el contador de posición en la frase y continuar recorriendo
    inc ebx
    jmp recorrer_frase

siguiente_palabra:
    ; Verificar si ya se ha almacenado la primera palabra
    cmp edi, palabra1
    je almacenar_palabra2
    cmp edi, palabra2
    je almacenar_palabra3
    cmp edi, palabra3
    jmp fin

fin:
    ; Inicializar registros
    mov ecx, 0       ; contador
    mov esi, palabra1   
    mov edi, select    

    comparar_caracteres:
        ; vamos conparando las letras
        mov al, [esi + ecx] 
        cmp al, [edi + ecx] 
        jne comprobarInsert ; si no es un select saltamos a comprobar si es un insert

        ; Verificar si se llegó al final de los strings
        cmp al, 0
        je selectDone   ;input == select

        ; Incrementar contador y continuar comparando
        inc ecx
        jmp comparar_caracteres

    comprobarInsert:
        ; Inicializar registros
        mov ecx, 0       ; contador
        mov esi, palabra1
        mov edi, insert    

    comparar_caracteresInsert:
        ; vamos comparando las letras
        mov al, [esi + ecx] 
        cmp al, [edi + ecx] 
        jne comprobarExit ; si no es un insert pasamos a comprobar si es un exit

        ; Verificar si se llegó al final de los strings
        cmp al, 0
        je insertDone   ;input == insert

        ; Incrementar contador y continuar comparando
        inc ecx
        jmp comparar_caracteresInsert

    insertDone:
        ; seleccionamos la palabra y su longitud
        mov ecx, palabra3
        mov eax, 5
        ; Añadir la extension basandonos en el lenght
        ; podriamos añadir byte a byte (inc eax)
        mov byte [ecx+eax-1], "."
        mov byte [ecx+eax], "t"
        mov byte [ecx+eax+1], "x"
        mov byte [ecx+eax+2], "t"

        add eax,4       ;añadimos a la longitud los 4 bytes extra
                        ;que hemos añadido

        ; El sistema operativo espera que las cadenas de texto
        ; acaben en un byte nulo
        ; Añadir al nombre de archivo con un byte nulo
        mov byte [ecx+eax-1], 0

        jmp abrirArchivo

    comprobarExit:
        ; Inicializar registros
        mov ecx, 0       ; contador
        mov esi, palabra1   
        mov edi, exitText  

    comparar_caracteresExit:
        ; vamos comprobando las letras
        mov al, [esi + ecx] 
        cmp al, [edi + ecx] 
        jne ordenNoEncontrada ; en caso de que no sea exit ni insert ni select mandamos mensajito al usuario

        ; Verificar si se llegó al final de los strings
        cmp al, 0
        je exit   ;input == exit

        ; Incrementar contador y continuar comparando
        inc ecx
        jmp comparar_caracteresExit

    selectDone:
        ;Preparar el input para poder abrir el archivo

        mov ecx, palabra3
        mov eax, 5
        ; Añadir la extension basandonos en el lenght
        ; podriamos añadir byte a byte (inc eax)
        mov byte [ecx+eax-1], "."
        mov byte [ecx+eax], "t"
        mov byte [ecx+eax+1], "x"
        mov byte [ecx+eax+2], "t"

        add eax,4       ;añadimos a la longitud los 4 bytes extra
                        ;que hemos añadido

        ; El sistema operativo espera que las cadenas de texto
        ; acaben en un byte nulo
        ; Añadir al nombre de archivo con un byte nulo
        mov byte [ecx+eax-1], 0

        jmp abrirArchivo

almacenar_palabra2:
    ; sobreescribimos el puntero al registro1 por el registro 2
    ; Inicializar los registros
    mov ecx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la palabra
    mov edi, palabra2 ; Dirección de la segunda palabra
    jmp siguiente_caracter

almacenar_palabra3:
    ; sobreescribimos el puntero al registro 2 por el registro 3
    ; Inicializar los registros
    mov ecx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la palabra
    mov edi, palabra3 ; Dirección de la tercera palabra
    jmp siguiente_caracter



;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<MANEJO DE ARCHIVOS>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



abrirArchivo:
    ;call nuevaLinea
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, saltoLinea
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ; Abrir el archivo en modo lectura
    mov eax, 5
    mov ebx, palabra3
    mov ecx, 0
    mov edx, 0
    int 80h
    test eax, eax
    js errorOpen_handling
    mov [fileIdentificator], eax  ; Guardar el descriptor

    ; Leer el contenido del archivo
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, eax
    mov ecx, content
    mov edx, 4096
    int 80h
    test eax, eax
    js errorReading_handling

    ; Mostrar el contenido del archivo
    ;mov eax, 4
    ;mov ebx, 1
    ;mov ecx, content
    ;int 80h

    ; Cerrar el archivo
    mov eax, 6
    mov ebx, [fileIdentificator]
    int 80h
    test eax,eax
    js errorClosing_handling


    ;<<<<<<<<Aqui empezamos la comprobacion de que devolver>>>>>>>>
    

    ; Inicializar registros
    mov ecx,0
    mov esi, palabra2
    mov edi, todo    

    comparar_caracteresPalabra2:
        ; vamos comparando las letras
        mov al, [esi] 
        cmp al, [edi] 
        jne imprimirSoloDeseado ; comprobar si es "*"

        ;En este caso no nos hace falta contador 
        ;ya que "*" solo tiene un byte

        ; Mostrar el contenido del archivo
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, content
        int 80h

        jmp _start

    imprimirSoloDeseado:
        ; Inicializar los registros
        mov ebx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la frase
        mov ecx, 0       ; Indicador de posición en la palabra
        mov edi, palabraAux ; Dirección de la primera palabra

        recorrer_fraseDeseado:
            ; Verificar si hemos llegado al final de la frase
            cmp ebx, longitud
            jge siguiente_palabraDeseado

            ; Obtener el carácter actual
            mov al, [content + ebx]

            ; Verificar si es un espacio en blanco
            cmp al, ";"
            je siguiente_palabraDeseado

            ; Almacenar el carácter en la palabra correspondiente
            mov [edi + ecx], al

            ; Incrementar el contador de posición en la palabra
            inc ecx
            jmp siguiente_caracterDeseado

        siguiente_caracterDeseado:
            ; Incrementar el contador de posición en la frase y continuar recorriendo
            ; call debug
            inc ebx
            jmp recorrer_fraseDeseado

        siguiente_palabraDeseado:
            ; el regitro se queda en palabraaux
            ; comprueba que palabra 2 esta dentro
            ; de palabraaux en ese caso imprime palabraaux                    
            jmp _start


exit:
    ; Salir del programa
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
    
;subrutina
debug:
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov eax, 4                  ; Número de llamada al sistema para escribir
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Descriptor de archivo (stdout)
    mov ecx, prueba            ; Puntero al mensaje
    mov edx, pruebaLen                ; Longitud del mensaje
    int 80h                       ; Llamar al sistema operativo

    ; restauramos desde la pila
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax

    ret



;<<<<<<<<<<<Apartado para errores>>>>>>>>>>>



ordenNoEncontrada:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, error3
    mov edx, errorLen3
    int 80h

    jmp _start

errorOpen_handling:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, error
    mov edx, errorLen
    int 80h

    jmp _start

errorClosing_handling:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, error4
    mov edx, errorLen4
    int 80h
    jmp _start

errorReading_handling:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, error2
    mov edx, errorLen2
    int 80h
    jmp _start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite algorithm uses repeated string operations [SCASB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) and [CMPSB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmps:cmpsb:cmpsw:cmpsd:cmpsq). When the first letter of searched Word is found, compare the rest of Word and if it doesn't match, restore pointer in Sentence and continue with the rest.

```
section .data
SentenceSize DD 27
WordSize     DD 3
Sentence     DB "guardar la de los archivos."
Word         DB "los"

section .text
        LEA EDI,[Sentence]
        LEA ESI,[Word]  
        MOV ECX,[SentenceSize]
        LODSB        ; Load the 1st letter of Word. ESI points at "os".
Search: REPNE SCASB  ; Search for the 1st letter of Word ("l").
        JNE NotFound 
; We have found 1st "l". EDI points at the following "a", ECX=18.
        PUSH ESI
        PUSH EDI
        PUSH ECX      
          MOV ECX,[WordSize]
          DEC ECX    ; The first letter of Word is already checked.        
          REPE CMPSB ; Set ZF=1 when the Word was found.
        POP ECX      ; Restore the remaining Sentence size (18).
        POP EDI      ; Restore Sentence pointer after "l".
        POP ESI      ; Restore Word pointer to "os".
        JNE Search   ; If ZF=0, search for "l" again. 2nd time it will succeed.
Found:   ; The Word was found in Sentence at the address EDI-1.
NotFound:; The Word is not present in Sentence.
```

Comment: This is just a slow and simple `memmem` , a substring match like `strstr`.  It will find `los` in the middle of `close`, not requiring it to be a *word* in a sentence.  IDK if that's what the OP meant or not; they weren't very specific and their code is a huge, and not commented in English. (OP says they're writing "their own SQL", so I'd recommend they do some reading about substring searching, including more efficient algorithms like Boyer-Moore, at least as something to maybe implement in the future.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, when finding `los` in `close` is not desirable, @7FULL would have to check whether both borders of the found Word are *word-separators*.

Comment: Note that `repe`/`repne`-string operations are *not* fast on current CPUs, except maybe Sapphire Rapids ([Which processors support "Fast Short REP CMPSB and SCASB"](//stackoverflow.com/q/75309389)) where they'll take a flat 15 cycles per operation with counts from 1 to 128-bytes long. (Current CPUs are worse).  That's not fast for a 3-byte string, even with branch mispredicts for doing it "normally" with loops and conditional branches.  Also, checking for a 2-byte initial match for strings that are at least 2 bytes long will greatly reduce false positives.  1-byte "words" reduce to `memchr`.

Comment: Thank you so much @vitsoft it works perfectly. You saved my life jjajjajajaja.